# Keep Socket Alive Across Requests

Tags: php, sockets

This might be a really ignorant question, but I have a need to create a socket when a person enters my application, use that socket for multiple operations, then dispose of it as soon as the person leaves the page.  I would immediately think of using the session array, but I'm not sure that would be the best for performance, but it may be my only option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Web Sockets would be ideal, but, correct me if I'm wrong, I don't own the socket server so I wouldn't be able to connect directly to it.  My main goal is to interact with a proprietary socket server, while keeping the context of the conversation alive (keep the socket open).

I can fit everything in on one page, but need to be able to interact with the user.

Comment: PHP can't really do that effectively, since every open connection ties up an entire PHP process on the web server. The best approach using PHP is to periodically poll a script using AJAX.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what you're trying to accomplish with this socket? Will you be using a Web Socket?

Comment: Sockets and sessions are two very different things. Can you elaborate what you want to do?

Comment: I was referring to storing the socket in the session.

Comment: @Benny You really need to explain what you're trying to accomplish, what you're asking for isn't really possible because it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Doesn't the traditional AJAX approach work for you and if so why not?

Comment: @deceze you might need to expand on "traditional AJAX"  For example, how would I reuse the same socket across AJAX calls?

Comment: @Benny Why do you need to reuse sockets, instead of making individual, RESTful AJAX calls? If you need 2-way communication, possibly pair that with Comet. Have you looked into these tried and true possibilities and if so, why aren't they sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to establish a socket connection from the client, you will need to use Web Sockets.  These are very new and are only supported in a few browsers.

If you need to keep a HTTP connection open, you can do that using AJAX, but only as long as the user stays on a single page.  You also may have to periodically close the connection and open a new one as many browsers will time out the connection after a short time.